# Filling content from bottom and right to left order

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Inside my page I have div which I want to populate with some content like it's on image. How can I do this without shrinking div content and populate inside div from bottom to up?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Best approach for this layout would be the **Flexbox Technique**

You can wrap the rows in the reverse order using `wrap-reverse`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.create').on('click', function() {
    $('.container').append('<div class="circle"></div>');
  })
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: #6CC4DA;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  align-items: baseline;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 280px;
  width: 770px;
}
.circle {
  background: #C78DEF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<button class="create">Create a circle</button>
```

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/hwk80pon/3/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

You can flip horizontal parent div and flip horizontal back each child block:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    var 
      items = $('.content-item').size(),
      space = document.createTextNode(' ');
    $('.container').append($('<div class="content-item">' + (items + 1) + '</div>')).append(space);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: cyan;
  transform: ScaleY(-1);
}
.content-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  transform: ScaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Increase population</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content-item">1</div>
  <div class="content-item">2</div>
  <div class="content-item">3</div>
  <div class="content-item">4</div>
  <div class="content-item">5</div>
  <div class="content-item">6</div>
  <div class="content-item">7</div>
</div>
```